# echo array values together based on same keys

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

Below is an array from which i need output that for each key i want to echo all the values together

Array ( [26] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 ) [28] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) )

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $array) {
        echo $key.'-'.$array.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Output using above code:
26-1
26-2
26-4
28-1

but the output which i want is that for each key i want to echo all the values.

Output which i want:
26-124
28-1

Answer (score 3):

PHP offers a basic function to concatenate array elements together, named [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' - ' . implode('', $value) . '<br>';
}
```

The first parameter is a glue, that specifies the string between the elements. It is currently the emtpy string `''`, so the `$value = [1, 2, 4]` will be printed as: `124`. If you provide a comma string as the glue (`','`) you will get `1,2,4` instead etc...

Comment: additional note: you can omit the first argument if you don't want them glued by any character `implode($value)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) as mentioned by other users, but if you want to use a foreach loop then your code should look like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo $key .'-';
    foreach ($value as $array) {
        echo $array;
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to combine the values of the child array before output it.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $array) {
        echo $key.'-'.implode('', $array).'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: this is incorrect, no need for another sub foreach since `implode` already takes care of that, at least test the code you're going to post

Comment: Yes, this throws an error. Either just print the `array` in the string, or remove that second foreach and then the implode will work. Though this would then be the same as @PhilippMaurer.